# Python, Special case to extract hostnames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, hostname

I've seen similar problems but mine is quite different and I can't solve it alone.

Given a line of text I want to extract only the hostname, below are examples of input - output pairs I'm expecting:

> Some Cool Text google.ru.ts -> google.ru.ts
>
> Ignore google.com Ignore -> google.com
>
> google.com/sign_in.htm -> google.com
>
> 13.59.135.97/wp-includes/fqhw5-6k88r-dgufy.view/ -> 13.59.135.97

I found a regex expression to match hostnames but it has some problems:

```
hostname_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})\b')
```

For the third example I get `in.htm` in the output (in addition to google.com)

For the forth one it returns fqhw5-6k88r-dgufy.view

How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) built-in library might be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps something like this? `(?<!\S)(?:(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\b` https://regex101.com/r/kug5k6/1

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex;

```
hostname_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?((?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})(?::[0-9]+)?(?=[/\s]|$)')
```

i tried the examples and the results are like this;

1. Some Cool Text google.ru.ts -> google.ru.ts
2. Ignore google.com Ignore -> google.com
3. google.com/sign_in.htm -> google.com
4. 13.59.135.97/wp-includes/fqhw5-6k88r-dgufy.view/ -> 13.59.135.97

Comment: Hi, for the 4th one it returned `fqhw5-6k88r-dgufy.view` as well

Comment: it's not clear plus it looks like chatgpt generated answer sorry I saw it generating exact same response... it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I've prefixed the regex with a `\b`, so it'll look like this:

```py
hostname_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})\b')
```

Now it's not going to match `in.html`. This solves for the 3rd sample.
For the fourth sample, you forgot to include the `0 - 9` range and the `+` sign in the regex. So the final regex would look like this:

```py
r'\b(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,})\b'
```

Here's my text code:

```py
inputs = [ i.split('>')[0].strip()  for i in """    Some Cool Text google.ru.ts -> google.ru.ts
    Ignore google.com Ignore -> google.com
    google.com/sign_in.htm -> google.com
    13.1234.1.321/wp-includes/fqhw5-6k88r-dgufy.view/ -> 13.59.135.97""".split('\n')]

regex = r'\b(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,})\b'
for i  in inputs:
    print(re.findall(regex, i))
```

This is the output:

```py
['google.ru.ts']
['google.com']
['google.com']
['13.1234.1.321', 'fqhw5-6k88r-dgufy.view']
```

Now it still returns the other 'match' for the fourth case, but you can just take the first element from the returned list and you're good.

Comment: why you added http and www inside your regex? I want to match hostname not URL

Comment: guys please stop using chatGPT...

Comment: Bro... that wasnt chatgpt at all lol. And the https and www were originally from your code, i just added my stuff to you regex 

Comment: Idk why u assumed i used chatgpt. I think most developers avoid using chatgpt for these kinda issues cuz it will just gove some garbage answer in a lot of casss

Comment: Btw for your question about not matching http and ww but matching the hostname instead. The regex includes them in (?:) along with the question mark after because maybe the http/www was before the hostname, so u would include the http, but not include it in the match.    Seems like yo're the one got your regex from chatgpt . Im sorry if it appears that i took the chatgpt note personally, but i hate it when people think you got your answer from chatgpt even though u would spend 15 mins on it lol. Good luck with ur stuff.

Comment: Hallo would you like to try the following regex? I've made it for you on regex101.com ^[a-zA-Z\.1-9]{1,}(?=\/)|\s{1,}\w{1,}\.\w{1,}\.\w{1,}|\s{1,}\w{1,}\.\w{1,}

Answer (score 0):

I've made a regex on regex101.com

It's the following, and I can say, that at least in the case you submitted, it works:

```
\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}| [a-zA-Z1-9\.]{1,}\.\w{2,3}|^[a-zA-Z1-9\.]{1,}\.\w{2,3}
```

You can check that [here](https://regex101.com/r/YpHSYm/1).

I've made also a little Python scripts that proves the mentioned above:

```py
import re

urls = ["google.com/sign_in.html",
"Ignore google.com Ignore",
"Some Cool Text google.ru.ts",
"13.59.135.97/wp-includes/fqhw5-6k88r-dgufy.view/"]

pattern = "\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}| [a-zA-Z1-9\.]{1,}\.\w{2,3}|^[a-zA-Z1-9\.]{1,}\.\w{2,3}"

for url in urls:
    host = re.findall(pattern, url)
    if host:
        print(host[0].strip())
```